# How can I force my phone to only use the KASUMI encryption?

Tags: security, cellular-data, cellular

Some of the most common forms of [cellular GSM signals have been hacked,](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4626/396) and I would like to ensure that my signals only use the more secure KASUMI encryption, even if it means that I don't have a reliable signal.

How can I ensure that my phone only uses the secure form of encryption of GSM?

Comment: Doesn't look like kasumi will help much with your concerns - http://www.maximumpc.com/article/news/new_128bit_gsm_encryption_cracked_just_2_hours .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on a windows phone.